# SQLite Empty database being referenced

Tags: iphone, ios, database, sqlite

Hoping someone can help a new iOS developer out - I have a ready made sqlite database called teamresults.db that I added to the project using "Add Files..." but when I'm using the below code I seem to be connecting/referencing an empty database instead of the one that's added (on inspection through the terminal the database the simulator uses is 0mb in size where as the one I've added is around 3mb).

It seems like the application is creating an empty database but I can't work out why? Any thoughts?

For reference I don't get any error messages:

```
BOOL success;
dbName = @"teamresults.db";

NSArray *documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
dbPath = [documentsDir   stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:dbPath];

if(success) {
    return;
}

NSString *databasePathFromApp = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:dbName];

[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePathFromApp error:nil];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be something wrong with this line of code:

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:databasePathFromApp error:nil];
```

The correct one would be:

```
[fileManager copyItemAtPath:databasePathFromApp toPath:dbPath error:nil];
```

You should copy database to sandbox path instead of resources path !!

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing. Delete the database added by right click on that and click delete instead of "Delete reference only". Then add it again and don't forget to click on "Copy into destination item". Hopefully that would help you.